# Binding issue with smpp server using jsmpp

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I have a java application which uses jsmpp library to send SMSs to SMSC. Application connects successfully and sends SMSs. Connection issue occurs after a week or so up time, during this up time it sends thousands of SMSs. But suddenly after few days application starts facing connection issues, some time 'Negative bind response 0x00045' and some time waiting bind response. When I check from wireshark, Application constantly sends enquire line packets and receives responses for them with status 'OK'. This means that application is connected but still it is attempting for new connection. Below is code for connection management.

I call newSession method to get session for SMS sending..

```
 private SMPPSession newSession(BindParameter bindParam) {
        SMPPSession tmpSession = null;
        dbOperations = new DBOperations();
        Settings settings = dbOperations.getSettings();
        if (settings == null)
            logger.error("ERROR: No settings found to connect to SMSC!");
        else {
            try {
                tmpSession = new SMPPSession(remoteIpAddress, remotePort, bindParam);
                tmpSession.addSessionStateListener(new MySessionStateListener());
                tmpSession.setMessageReceiverListener(new DeliverReceiptListener());
                tmpSession.setEnquireLinkTimer(50000);
                tmpSession.setTransactionTimer(5000L);
                logger.info("New session established with " + remoteIpAddress + " on port " + remotePort + " as Transmitter");
            } catch (Exception er) {
                gateway=null;
                logger.error("Exception Occurred While making Connection with SMPP Server with IP: " + remoteIpAddress + " and port " + remotePort+" and Error is:"+er.getMessage());
            }

        }
        return tmpSession;
    }


public void reconnectAfter(final long timeInMillis) {
        final Settings settings = dbOperations.getSettings();
        if (settings == null) {
            logger.error("No settings found to connect to SMSC!");
            return;
        }
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                logger.info("Schedule reconnect after " + timeInMillis + " milliseconds");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeInMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }

                int attempt = 0;
                while (session == null || session.getSessionState().equals(SessionState.CLOSED)) {
                    try {
                        logger.info("Reconnecting attempt #" + (++attempt) + "...");
                        session = newSession(bindParam);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Failed opening Transmitter connection and bind to " + remoteIpAddress + ":" + remotePort + " ");
                        logger.error(e.getMessage());
                        // wait for a second
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(reconnectInterval);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ee) {
                            logger.error(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
    private class MySessionStateListener implements SessionStateListener {

        public void onStateChange(SessionState newState, SessionState oldState, Object o) {
            if (newState.equals(SessionState.OPEN)) {
                logger.info("TCP connection established with SMSC at address " + remoteIpAddress);
            }
            if (newState.equals(SessionState.BOUND_TRX)) {
                logger.info("SMPP Transceiver connection established with SMSC at address " + remoteIpAddress + " and port " + remotePort);
            }
            if (newState.equals(SessionState.CLOSED) || newState.equals(SessionState.UNBOUND)) {

                logger.error("Connection closed, either by SMSC or there is network problem");
                if(newState.equals(SessionState.CLOSED))
                    logger.error("Connection closed");
                else
                    logger.error("Connection unbound");
                logger.info("Reconnecting.......");
                reconnectAfter(reconnectInterval);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't why this code retries for fresh connection when it is already connected. Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the session still valid.
Make sure there are no zombie session, if there are any then close them all. It make sure the enquire link sending stop.

Comment: If session is still valid then why reconnectAfter method gets called from SessionStateListener, do you suggest any changes to above code ?
How whould I know if there are any zombie sessions ?